# How to know when an app has been launched from scratch using Default.png?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is there a way to know for sure that the app has been launched from scratch, meaning it hasn't been awaked from the background but really started up out of nowhere including the display of Default.png or Default-iPad.png?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your App delegate there is a method,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Only at launch" message:@""   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this method only gets called when the app is launched from scratch?

Comment: Yes 100% sure :), As far as I know this method only gets called at fresh launch..this is the only chance for developer to setting up application for data or start notification such as wether device is connected to internet or not :)